# Constraints that set values to binary variables depending on other binaries

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, constraint, linearization, binary-variable

I am trying to write a mathematical problem that involves some conditions based on binary variables. More specifically, I have a set of three binary variables $d_1$, $d_2$, $d_3$ and depending on their values, I want to have some other binary variables $y_1,\ldots,y_5$ activated according to the following table:

|  | $y_1$ | $y_2$ | $y_3$ | $y_4$ | $y_5$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $d_1$ | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| $d_2$ | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| $d_3$ | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

For instance, $y_1$ is equal to 1 if and only if $d_1$ is equal to 1. Same goes for the pairs $(y_2,d_2)$ and $(y_3,d_3)$. $y_4$ becomes equal to 1 if both $d_1$ and $d_2$ are 1. Finally, $y_5$ becomes 1 if all of $d_1$, $d_2$ and $d_3$ are equal to 1.

Moreover, at the same time, only one of $y_1,\ldots,y_5$ can be activated, which is to formulate as $\sum y_i = 1$.

I am having problems though formulating the other constraints regarding the $d_i$, $y_i$ variables.

I have tried formulating the following set of constraints for $y_5$:

$$y_{\rm intermediate} \geq d_1 + d_2 - 1$$

This will allow $y_{\rm intermediate}$ to become 1 if both $d_1$ and $d_2$ are activated.

Then, I could have: \begin{align}y_5 &\geq y_{\rm intermediate} + d_3 - 1\\y_4&\geq y_{\rm intermediate} + (1 - d_3) - 1\end{align}

Then depending on the value of $d_3$ either $y_5$ or $y_4$ will become equal to 1.

However, I am having trouble formulating the rest of the constraints for $y_1$ to $y_3$ and I am also not sure if what I already have is good enough.

Does anyone have any pointers or ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following enforces your desired behavior:
\begin{align}
y_1 &= d_1 \\
y_2 &= d_2 \\
y_3 &= d_3 \\
y_4 &\ge d_1 + d_2 - 1\\
y_5 &\ge d_1 + d_2 + d_3 - 2\\
\end{align}
If you also want to enforce
$y_4 \implies (d_1 \land d_2)$
and
$y_5 \implies (d_1 \land d_2 \land d_3)$,
then include these additional constraints:
\begin{align}
y_4 &\le d_1 \\ 
y_4 &\le d_2 \\ 
y_5 &\le d_1 \\ 
y_5 &\le d_2 \\ 
y_5 &\le d_3 
\end{align}

---

On second thought, your comment about only one $y_i$ being activated makes me think that, instead of $y_1 = 1 \iff d_1 = 1$, you meant $y_1 = 1 \iff (d_1,d_2,d_3) = (1,0,0)$.  Equivalently, $y_1 = d_1(1-d_2)(1-d_3)$, which you can linearize as follows:
\begin{align}
y_1 &\le d_1 \\
y_1 &\le 1 - d_2 \\
y_1 &\le 1 - d_3 \\
y_1 &\ge d_1 + (1 - d_2) + (1 - d_3) - 2
\end{align}
You could similarly set up four linear inequality constraints for each of the other $y_i$ and then impose $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5=1$.  But a simpler formulation is just to treat the table entries as the constraint coefficients:
\begin{align}
y_1 + y_4 + y_5 &= d_1 \\
y_2 + y_4 + y_5 &= d_2 \\
y_3 + y_5 &= d_3 \\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 &= 1
\end{align}